# I could use regex expressions with the unix utility 'find'?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, find

I wondering if I could search some sentence from files '.html' with the utility find where exists something like this http://...jquery$ between them. I just did something like this, but obviously doesn´t work. How can I search those sentences.

$ find ./ -iname '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nir 'http://*.json$'

I mean, I could use regex expressions like $ just above?

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: 1. the provided link does not work
2. unclear what you are asking for. please consider reformatting to attract more help.

Comment: Your example with `find` and `xargs` is just what I was about to suggest -- that's a standard and useful idiom.  What about it is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

The `find` also need to use regex expressions, so I just fix it with "*":

```
find . -iname '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nir 'http://*.json$'
```

Comment: Yeah, actually I improve my searching method, doing it like this: _italic_ **bold** `find ./ -iname '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nir -e 'http:\/\/.json$' -e 'https:\/\/*.json$'`

Comment: Firstly, it is not necessary to escape `/`. Secondly, `*` means matching the previous element zero or more times. so it has covered the former `'http:\/\/.json$'`. Besides, `.` is also a wildcard which matches any single character. For the reason that I think you should use `\.` to escape `.` if you really means the punctuation `.`